# Can Lipschitz fixed points converge in $R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

I was wondering whether the following proposition is true. If it's not true, can there be any interesting counterexamples?

Proposition: Let $f:X\subset R^n\mapsto R^m$ be a smooth map on a compact set $X$ and $\{x_k\}\subset R^n$ be a sequence of Lipschitz fixed points of $f$ (that is, $\forall x_k, f(x_k)=x_k$ and $df_{x_k}$ does not have eigenvalue 1 ), such that $lim_{k\to\infty}x_k=x_0$. Then $x_0$ is a fixed point but not a lipschitz fixed point.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you want the $x_k$ to be **distinct** (or at least infinitely many $x_k \ne x_0$).

Hint: take  a subsequence such that $(x_k - x_0)/\|x_k - x_0\|$ has a limit.